# Разделить генератор чисел Javascript

Tags: javascript

Код такой:

```
<html>
<script>
var player = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
if (player = 1)
{ alert ("pobeda") }
if (player = 2)
{ alert ("loser") }
</script>
</html>
```

Я запустил эту программу в компиляторе anWriter Free.
Сначала у меня вылезает надпись "pobeda", а потом надпись "loser". Мне надо чтобы вылезала одна надпись. Как?

Comment: `=` -> `==`....

Comment: `alert(["pobeda", "loser"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]);`

Comment: Попробовал написать "==" , такой же результат.

Comment: @АнтонСергеев Вы не поменяли второе присваивание на сравнение - `if (player = 2)`

Comment: @АнтонСергеев Учтите, что переменная `player` никогда не будет равна двум.

Comment: Я написал : var player = Math.floor(Math.random()*3); результат такой же.